# I am receiving the error 'List::showList' : function-style initializer appears to be a function definition' on a function in my cpp file

Tags: c++

GithubLinkhttps://github.com/leomdmfiel/Assignment/tree/master/BankManager/BankManager
First here's my header:

```
class List
{
protected:
    Node* head;
public:
    List(object data);
    void addNode(Node* headRef, object data);
    void removeNode();
    void showList(Node* headRef);
};
```

And here is the function showList

```
void List::showList(Node* headRef)
{   Node* current = headRef;
    while (current != NULL) 
    {
        cout << current->retrieveData();
        current = current->retrieveNext();
    }   
}
```

For some reason at compile it keeps giving me the error error C2448: 'List::showList' : function-style initializer appears to be a function definition even though I've copied the declaration letter by letter. So I'm at a loss and looking for help.

Comment: I would guess missing braces or semi-colons in the code preceding `List::showList`.

Comment: In the code preceding List::showList, since you haven't posted that code I can't be more specific. Just a guess of course.

Comment: Here's a clue, post the code that is before the line where you get the error message. I am assuming (you didn't say) that the line with the error message is `void List::showList(Node* headRef)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that I've seen the code you have an extra semi-colon

```
#include"List.h";
```

should be

```
#include"List.h"
```

I would have expected a better error message though, I must admit.

Comment: Didn't catch that, on recompile though it still gives some errors. Including the same one.

Comment: OK, what errors, what code. I think we need to see the header file as well. And the other errors.

Comment: That was it? That's not a very good error message at all. Sure the compiler wasn't seeing the function definition, however, I feel like it could have stated that something like "WTF? Where are all my declarations/ what is this List class you speak of?"

Comment: [link](https://github.com/leomdmfiel/Assignment/tree/master/BankManager/BankManager) I have it up on github if it helps, the files in question are List.h and List.cpp

Comment: OK, object.h missing semi-colon, `class object { ... }` should be `class object { ... };`. Same error in node.h. No include guards in any header file. Have you ever had this code compiling? It has a lot of errors.

Comment: In customer.h an extra semi-colon. `#include"object.h";` should be `#include"object.h"`. You really need to learn where to place semi-colons. Clearly the semi colons missing from some places are being partly compensated for by the extra semi-colons in other places.

Comment: include guards? they've never come up in class and yet it was compiling before I started implementing list stuff.

Comment: OK, well google them. You might not need them in your particular program, you're going to have to learn about them soon however. Definitely needed as your programs get more complex.

Comment: OK will do, now I'm getting the error "List is not a Class" after making those fixes.

Comment: Well without knowing what your current code looks like or which line has that error it's very hard to help.

Comment: I've resynced my github so if you look now the code will be updated. [link](http://pastebin.com/bwVHVQE0) the errors are now different.

Comment: Wiki article on include guard. [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing seems to be wrong with the function you gave, check the code above the function in case you forgot a semi-colon.

edit: Make sure you also check where the function is located, make sure it is in the right file, it could be something as small as the wrong file.

Comment: I checked and it doesn't seem to be either of those things.
EDIT: heres the code [link](http://pastebin.com/rUcUMT9D)

Answer (score 0):

Try rebuilding the solution.

Sometimes in Visual Studio there are problems linking files. The potential cause of this is beyond my level of understanding, but sometimes rebuilding the solution cures a problem like this.

So it could be that the cpp file is out-of-date so to speak.

Personally, from what I can see, there doesn't appear to be an issue.